# Django - Design choices, Override the model save() so it palys nice with contrib.admin?

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm with some design issues in Django and getting all to play nice with **contrib.admin**.

My main problem is with **Admin Inlines** and the **save_formset()** method. I created a create() classmethod for the model but this do not play nice with save_formset(). I think Django admin have a way of doing this, not with a create() method. In the create() method in the AdPrice I basicaly want to update the field 'tags' in the model Ad.

My question: Instead of creating a create() classmethod it would be nice to override the model **save()** method so I don't have problems with contrib.admin?

My code:

Models:

```
class Ad(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    tags = TaggableManager()
    comment = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    user_inserted = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, related_name='user_inserted_ad')
    date_inserted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user_updated = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, related_name='user_updated_ad')
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class AdPrice(models.Model):
    ad = models.ForeignKey(Ad)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    user_inserted = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, related_name='user_inserted_ad_price')
    date_inserted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user_updated = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, related_name='user_updated_ad_price')
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, ad_id, name, price, date_inserted, user_inserted_id):
        # Save price
        new_register = AdPrice(ad_id=ad_id, name=name, price=price, date_inserted=date_inserted,
                       user_inserted=User.objects.get(id=user_inserted_id))
        new_register.save()

        # Add tags to Ad tags field
        # AD SOME CODE HERE # To do
```

Admin:

```
class AdPriceInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = AdPrice

    fieldsets = (
    (None, {
        'fields': ('name', 'price')
    }),
    )

class AdAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'name', 'title', 'telephone', 'comment', 
                    'user_inserted', 'date_inserted', 'user_updated', 'date_updated')

    fieldsets = (
    (None, {
        'fields': ('id', 'name', 'title', 'description', 'comment')
    }),
    )

    inlines = (
    AdPriceInline,
    )

    readonly_fields = ('id',)

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if change == False:
            if getattr(obj, 'user_inserted', None) is None:
                obj.user_inserted = request.user
                super(AdAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change) # This line save the data on the Ad Model, now I have the pk to use bellow
                obj.save()

                # In the first insert, create a line in the AdHist model
                # ad_status_id = 1 (Pending) | ad_change_reasons = 1(Insertion)
                AdHist.create(ad_id=obj.id, datetime_begin=datetime.datetime.now(), datetime_end=None, ad_status_id=1, ad_change_reason_id=1, 
                          user_inserted_id=request.user.id)

        elif change == True: 
            if getattr(obj, 'user_updated', None) is None:
                obj.user_updated = request.user
            else:
                obj.user_updated = request.user

            if getattr(obj, 'date_updated', None) is None:
                obj.date_updated = datetime.datetime.now()
            else:
                obj.date_updated = datetime.datetime.now()

            obj.save()

    def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):

        if change == False:

            instances = formset.save(commit=False)
            for instance in instances:
                if formset.model == AdPrice:
                    AdPrice.create(ad_id=instance.ad_id, name=instance.name, price=instance.price, date_inserted=datetime.datetime.now(), 
                               user_inserted_id=request.user.id) 

        elif change == True:

            for form in formset.forms:
                None #form.instance.ad_id
            formset.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

A tricky part about overriding a model's `save()` method is that it doesn't get used in bulk operations, like [`bulk_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create). Django recommends using a [signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_save) for a case like this (see [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/signals/) on how to set them up in your app).

Your signal might look something like this:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

from .models import YourModel


def handle_model_post_save(sender, **kwargs):
    # Ensure we are only running this code on create
    if kwargs['created'] and kwargs['instance']:
        # Your logic goes here
```

With this, the code in the signal will only run when a new instance of your model is created, not when existing instances are updated.